# Telnet cannot enter POST body parameters

Tags: http

I need to use Telnet to send http request messages, but when sending POST, Telnet stops me from entering the body parameters and ends it directly for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWBwF.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet may not be the best choice for sending an HTTP request (something like `nc` is generally a better alternative for raw requests, or otherwise `wget`, `curl` etc, if you're happy for someone else to do the heavy lifting).

What are you looking to achieve?